# Selenium: InvalidSelectorException with XPath child::node()

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

So having a WebElement in Selenium, I am trying to get all of its direct childs by XPath including text nodes. I already tried the XPath "*" which works but doesn't give me any text node (if there is any). According to XPath's documentation I then tried many things:

- "child::node()" gives me InvalidSelectorException.
- Tried to get all the nodes with "*" and then trying to get all the text nodes with "text()": gives me InvalidSelectorException on the "text()" query.

I tried these XPaths with the XPathHelper extension on Chrome and it works as intented but it doesn't seem to work with Selenium (Chrome WebDriver and PhantomJS).

This is my loop that I thought should work:

```
for(WebElement child : node.findElements(new By.ByXPath("child::node()"))) {
    //Do something with child
}
```

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
public String getHiddenText(WebDriver driver, WebElement aWebElement) {
    return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", aWebElement);
}
```

Addressing crawljax comment,

```
public String getHiddenText(EmbeddedBrowser browser, WebElement aWebElement) {
    WebDriver driver = browser.getDriver();
    return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", aWebElement);
}
```

I find that the best way to learn a new tool is to go to its [github repository](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax) and search the automated tests for examples of how to use it.  Just saying.  :-)

Comment: @Faterou text nodes can be a pain.  The Selenium getText() method tries to shield you from this but it doesn't work in all cases.  My method is called getHiddenText because the Selenium getText() method doesn't return text when the element is hidden.  But it will return complex text node text whether hidden or not.  One caveat, it will return non-ASCII characters if present so I often add .replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", ""); to the call.

Comment: That probably works well thanks for that! The only problem is I'm using Selenium through Crawljax and I don't have direct access to the driver; I have access through the interface EmbeddedBrowser that has a function called executeJavaScript(String), so I can't put any argument. I know I didn't specify this in the question so I guess this is resolved...

Comment: Also, textContent returns the text value of all the descendants and I just want the direct child.

Comment: Pass in just one child element.  For example, child[0].

Comment: Addressing your Crawljax edit, getDriver() definitely once was a function in the interface but isn't there in more recent versions.

Comment: Which version are you using? 3.6 [supports getDriver](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/686863ec5c70d95e8943b118b9e79d47eaca8e40/core/src/test/resources/demo-site/invariants.html).

Comment: Change that to Java version 3.51 supports getDriver.